# Postcss-extend. 'class not found' when file is @imported from node_modules folder?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, laravel-mix

Hello I'm getting an error where the extend module can't find a class contained within an imported file located in the 'node_modules' directory.

#### Error message

```
error  in ./resources/assets/pcss/app.pcss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
  @extend .relative; // fails
         ^
      ".footer" failed to @extend ".relative".
The selector ".relative" was not found.
```

#### app.pcss file

```
@import '../../../node_modules/basscss-position/index.css'; /* contains .relative */
/* @import 'basscss-position/index.css';  this also fails */
@import "./test.pcss"; /* contains .bg-primary */

.footer {
  @extend .bg-primary; /* works */
  @extend .relative; /* fails */
}
```

#### webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix'); // aka webpack wrapper that makes things simple
let convertLength = require('convert-css-length');
let convert = convertLength('13px');

mix.sass('resources/assets/pcss/app.pcss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('postcss-import')(),
            require('postcss-cssnext')({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']}),
            require('postcss-extend')()
        ]
    })
```

#### Add to script object in package.json

```
script: {
  "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --
progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

I've noticed that if I change the node_module file from .css to .pcss then it will work but I'm not sure why and I don't really want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue in the past, the thing is this is not a bug of **postcss-extend**, you should report this bug in **postcss-import** or simply you can replace your **postcss-import** dependency with **postcss-simple-import** which is far better and managed properly by developers.